# Getting pushed key value in node js firebase

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My Database Structure is like the following,

```
child{
      0{
        name:true
       },
      1{
        name2:true
       }
    }
```

I want to get the index number (i.e. 0,1) . I only know the name(name,name2)

I tried the following code but it's returning null. And

My Firebase Value Event listener is like the following which is not working and i have to get the name of the key value.

```
ref.push().child(name).once("value",function(snapshot){

});
```

. Need Help . Thank you.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do from your code... `ref.push()` does not persist anything if you don't provide data so this code effectively does nothing. Can you clarify?

Comment: I edited the question. Please check @MichaelBleigh

Comment: I want to select a random name from that child. As there is no direct method to select a random no. So i thought i'll add all new names in childcount+1 index then i'll select a random no. in between 0 to children count. That's how i can get a random name. Do u know any better ways to do this? @MichaelBleigh